# Cannot read property 'isInstalled' of undefined. On Appium higher than 1.3.7

Tags: ios, appium

I use Appium 1.3.7 and iPhone.
After upgrading Appium to version 1.4.13 I received next error:
"Cannot read property 'isInstalled' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show us some code ?